# Boost document in solr where document's field contains some value

Tags: solr

I have documets in solr in below format

```
{   "documents": [    {
      "custom_string_New Arrival": "false",
      "custom_string_Brand Name": "GB",
      "custom_string_Product Name": "GB GB Girls Big Girls 7%2D16 Flutter%2DSleeve Jumpsuit",
      "score": 11.223517,
      "id": "67012"
    },
    {
      "custom_string_New Arrival": "false",
      "custom_string_Brand Name": "Lucy Paris",
      "custom_string_Product Name": "Lucy Paris Knit Camille Sleeveless Belted Jumpsuit",
      "score": 11.223517,
      "id": "50097"
    }   ] }
```

I want boost a document whose custom_string_Product Name contains "Paris Knit"
I am creating a solr query with query parameter

> bq=(custom_string_Product\ Name:(*Paris Knit*))^5000

I am expecting that the document with id= 50097 should come at the top, but i am not getting the expected result.
But if if do

> bq=(custom_string_Product\ Name:(*Knit*))^5000

then I get the correct response.

the difference is only that in first query there is a space in between the search term.

Comment: whats is the field type for your field? try to have the fieldtype as string and then try...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Its of type string only.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using wildcard queries (i.e. a  `*` is present), most analysis is skipped (except those that are multitermaware, which are a few filters). In this case it simply doesn't work because there is no tokens matching `Paris Knit` - the tokens are probably stored as `paris` and `knit` (and not as one single token).

You can use either a string type field or a KeywordTokenizer for the field type - the KeywordTokenizer allows you to add a `LowercaseFilter` as well, so that your boosts becomes case insensitive.

Comment: "Paris Knit" this is a single token and not separate ones.

"custom_string_Product Name": "Lucy Paris Knit Camille Sleeveless Belted Jumpsuit",

Comment: In that case it's probably because you're not escaping the space between the tokens properly: `bq=(custom_string_Product\ Name:(*Paris Knit*))^5000` should be `bq=(custom_string_Product\ Name:(*Paris\ Knit*))^5000`